# iOS 5 Twitter API behaves differently in the Simulator vs real iOS device

Tags: ios, twitter, ios5

I encountered this behavior when running an app on the simulator and on the iPad:

Sending tweet with picture attachment using TWTweetComposeViewController, on the Simulator I can send a very large picture file (>5MB).  But when I run the same app on the iPad, the same picture file did not go through only the text message did.  A smaller picture files, 200k for example, have no problem.  I know 5MB is large for a tweet.  But I just want to find out is this some type of bug?

Comment: Have you checked whether there were out-of-memory warnings on the iPad when you compose the attachment? The device doesn't use paging files.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be due to discrepancy between device and simulator . Please re-check it with the below links. I would suggest you to go through the following tutorial which I found best on web once:

http://iosdevelopertips.com/core-services/ios-5-twitter-framework-part-1.html

Plus, this one is also awesome with a lot of detail and simplified explanation from Ray. I follow his blog for same. http://www.raywenderlich.com/5519/beginning-twitter-in-ios-5